# How to create a Wildfly 14 server in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I installed JBoss integration for Eclipse:

[image]

But when I try to add a new server by going to the Servers view -> right click -> new -> Server I get no option for Wildfly 14:

[image]

I downloaded 14.0.1. How do I add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick `Wildfly 13` for now, and wait for the update of JBoss Tools.
Wildfly 14 is supported in [JBoss Tools 4.9.0.AM3](https://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools/2018-09/4.9.0.AM3.html) development version,
 see [release notes](https://tools.jboss.org/documentation/whatsnew/jbosstools/4.9.0.AM3.html)
You can install this version in Eclipse (first uninstall the earlier one), however this version may be unstable.

Comment: Are there no consequences for doing so? Why does it ask about the version if I can point it to any installation?

Comment: Consequences ? I think that nobody knows that, you can test it yourself. At the moment, you have no other choice - either use WildFly 13+stable JBoss Tools plugin and wait for the update OR use Widlfly 14 + stable JBoss Tools plugin & choose version 13 in the plugin OR use WildFly 14 and instal the newest development version of plugin (which supports WildFly 14 but may be unstable).

Answer (score 1):

After updating (help-> Check for updates) the option appears ...

[wildfly14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1DGw.png)

Comment: Yes, they added it in the latest JBoss tools version.

Comment: I have updated(help-> Check for updates), also updated JBOSS though marketplace but i can't  see wildfly 13, 14 listed in my eclipse oxygen. Any specific reason.

Comment: Update to: Photon

Answer (score 0):

Even if Widfly 14 is not available as such in Eclipse, it's yet possible. Just choose the 'Wildfly 13' server type, and (in next step) point to a local Wildfly 14 installation.

Comment: Are there no consequences for doing so? Why does it ask about the version if I can point it to any installation?

Comment: You can point to any version at the condition this version is starting exactly the same way (eg same bootstrap class, same command line arguments, etc...) as WF13. There is no such difference between WF 13 and 14, so that Eclipse can start both of them the same way.